# Proposing multiple association bonuses

Tags: feature-request, association-bonus

Stack Exchange only has one 100-reputation association bonus awarded when one of your accounts crosses the 200 reputation mark. This is a problem because a user can have access to moderator tools at 10K reputation but still doesn't have enough reputation to downvote in other communities.

I propose multiple association bonuses:

- Reach 200 reputation on a site, and have joined 2 or more sites => Gain 100 reputation on all sites
- Reach 500 reputation on a site, and have joined 2 or more sites => Gain 200 reputation on all sites
- Reach 2000 reputation on a site, and have joined 2 or more sites => Gain 300 reputation on all sites
- Reach 10000 reputation on a site, and have joined 2 or more sites => Gain 500 reputation on all sites

Comment: why not simply propose to reduce the rep required to downvote? Also if this is about downvoting why have the 2000 and 10000 rep rules since 125 rep allows you to downvote.

Comment: So, if you register on 12 sites, you pass Go and collect 200 rep?

Comment: You entrust someone who has 10k on 1 site to access First Review/Last Answer queues on *all sites* just after joining a site they probably don't have any idea what's good or not on there?

Comment: As far I can  see you didn't earn that rep bonus at any site you're participating. Your feature request sounds just weird regarding that little of background knowledge at all

Comment: With regards to the above comment, I suggest reading the third section of the answer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying

Comment: This feature request as so many problems and I think it is a really bad idea.

Comment: I think it would be a fine tuning of the SE, helping others to learn and know many SE sites. I find its score absolutely not surprising. :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main reason you get 100 reputation is because the privileges at that level are universal across the network, the main ones being comment everywhere, upvoting, and flagging.

Anything above that should come with a decent understanding of that specific SE site.  The first one is downvoting, and one I see as an incredibly valuable action for site quality.  You should have at least a grasp of the quirks and foibles of the community before allowing you to decide something isn't useful.

Creating tags, *especially*, shouldn't be handed out instantly.  They're complicated enough, and each site has a slightly different take on it that even experienced users get it wrong.  Giving it to brand new users is just asking for additional cleanup efforts.

Comment: Does this high level of knowledge behind all the SE sites help to improve their visitor and activity stats?

Comment: @peterh I fail to see how that is at all relevant to the question.

Comment: I think it would work as a reward, and also as a help for strongly distributed cross-site activities. For example, in your case, I simply disbelieve that you could not correctly help newbies on the pets SE, despite that you have only 200 there. Simply because your arcade SE 17k gave far enough cross-network experience for that, in my opinion. However, additional privileges should be used for good, I think a 500 (or 350 on betas) used only to VLQ flag newbie posts instead advicing them is not a productive activity.

Comment: @peterh Why do users *need* a reward to use other sites?  You're coming at this from a completely incorrect premise.

Comment: On these reasons, I disbelieve that a deep knowledge of the topics of the site would exist, maybe a knowledge of the community and site politics would be helpful. But, for the first-posts/late-answers review, even this is not needed. What is needed: strong urge to help newbies and fix first-posts network-wide.

Comment: @peterh The premise is not what they need, the premise is that on what conditions would it be useful.

Comment: @peterh No.  Just...no.  Goodbye.